# Why are new rows not being added to ag-grid using vuejs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I've got an ag-grid component in a vue.js application declared like this:

```
<ag-grid-vue :enable-sorting="false"
                                 :enable-filtering="false"
                                 :suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns="true"
                                 :rowData="category.policyDocuments"
                                 :gridOptions="policyGridOptions"
                                 @cellValueChanged="savePolicyRow"
                                 @grid-ready="onPolicyGridReady($event, category)"
                                 class="w-100"
                                 style="height: 200px">
</ag-grid-vue>
```

Bound to this typescript view model:

```
export class PolicyListViewModel {
    status: PolicyDashboardStatus;

    policyLists: DocumentWalletPolicyDocumentList[] = [];

    gridApi: GridApi | null = null;

    policyDocuments: DocumentWalletDocumentViewModel[] = [];

    constructor(status: PolicyDashboardStatus) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    get shouldShow(): boolean {
        return this.policyDocuments.length > 0;
    }

    updateDocuments(): void {
        this.policyDocuments = this.policyLists
            .map(list => list.policyDocuments)
            .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
    }
}
```

When my page first displays I get the right data. When I call `updateDocuments` with new data the grid does not update. I have verified in vue devtools that the `rowData` prop is being updated. ag-grid documentation would suggest that the component should react to the change. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: With ag grid you can use [transactions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update-transactions/) to update the row data. You don't just directly set it as you in the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DigitalDrifter, but in this case I'm not making the changes to the data client side, but refreshing from the server. The documentation says *"The easiest way to update data inside the grid is to replace the data you gave it with a fresh set of data. This is done by either updating the rowData bound property (if using a framework) or calling api.setRowData(newData)."*, see: [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/).

Comment: My previous comment is [mentioned](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#transaction) in the link you provided  as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
 :row-data="Array.from(rowData)"
```

or

```
:row-data="[...rowData]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah-ha. Finally figured it out, posting here in case it helps anyone else.

It looks like my problem was binding both `gridOptions` and `rowData` at the same time. Everything was working fine *except* for the the refresh when `rowData` was changed. I'm assuming this is because the grid options had its own `rowData` property and the ag-grid wrapper was using the data from one copy and detecting changes on the other (or something like that).

I replaced the `gridOptions` binding with a `columnDefs` binding (in this case the only options I needed to set) and everything started working exactly as it should.